# In Vim, Number repeats itself unintentionally

Tags: ubuntu, vim, normal-mode

Whenever I'm in insert mode and type any number and then press Esc button to go to Normal mode, the number repeats itself several times. How should I resolve it.

[image]

Comment: You obviously typed in some numbers before entering insert mode, which will cause the insert to be executed that amount of times. Stop doing that and your problem is solved :-P

Answer (score 0):

The `i` / `a` / ... commands that enter insert mode take a `[count]`. So, if you enter insert mode via `5i`, the entered text will be duplicated *four more times* (total of *5*) after leaving insert mode.

This is a Vi(m) feature. If you unintentionally use this, learn to type more precisely; it's an important skill in Vim.